# Fieldmap pop up showing fields not setup in form

Tags: arcgis-field-maps

I’ve set up a Fieldmaps form for data collection and used conditional visibility to control what field are shown during data collection. The map is set up for high precision and editor tracking so there are a lot of background fields that are not filled by the observer. This issue I’m running into is that the background fields still show up on the feature pop-up.  What do I need to do to hide those fields?